# Difference between "read-only" and "write-protected"

Tags: expressions

Essentially, both mean the same, so is there any clear difference in the meaning of those two words?

Comment: They do not mean the same. Generally, you only can do X is not the same as you cannot do Y.

Comment: If it's "read-only", it might mean that you may not make a copy. "Write-protected" doesn't imply that.

Comment: It's partial explanation but for me 'write-protected' means that something is technically capable of being written on but some additional action have been performed - say wire blocked/fuse blown etc. while 'read-only' does not implies that. Example: ["By applying write protection, some types of reprogrammable ROMs may temporarily become read-only memory."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory#Types).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computing terminology, not the English Language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say the difference is in emphasis.

You would use "write protected" if you were talking about preventing an accidental modification to contents. For example, modifying a floppy disk or a video/audio cassette so that it can't be accidentally over-written.

You would talk about "read-only" when it's a limitation. For example, you'd say "This word document is read-only" to indicate why you aren't able to make a modification you want to make to it.

Comment: To expand on the concept of context, as an American IT professional, I would not use the term "write-protected" when referring to file level permissions.  Typically, "write-protected" is used in reference to storage media such as LTO tapes, rewritable discs, and drives, whereas "read only" is a file level permission.

Answer (score 3):

Read Only

> meaning you can't change what is on it
>
> some of the disk which we have used comes with Read-Only mode, it means we can't change in that once it is written on it.

write-protected

> Write-protected means you can only be read; you cannot write to them, edit them, append data to them, or delete them.

it is basically used for devices. like USB drive,floppy disk with device like USB you can not use word like

> My USB drive is in read only mode.

but you can say with your files that is reside in your system.. that `my file is in read only mode..`

Answer (score 1):

Well grammatically speaking, read-only excludes any action other than reading, whereas write-protected means you can do anything with it except writing, in your context I would not inmediatly know what other actions their could possibly be, but considering you are on english.stackexchange, yes, there is a clear difference in meaning.

Comment: Perhaps add examples, such as many pdf files are write-protected (cannot be modified) but are not read-only (they can be copied, saved, moved, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, couldn't think of examples, those only apply to files btw, I was thinking about hardware in which you have reading and writing, amd those are all the operations you can do.

Comment: Read-only implies write-protected; the converse is not necessarily true. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic) for some more mathematical background.)
For instance, a write-protected document could be read-protected for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

*Read* and *write* refer to data.

**Read-only**

If data is truly *read-only* you can read it with a device, but you cannot do any other operation to it. You cannot modify it, erase it, append to it, concatenate it, copy it, or move it. You can read it. This is a key factor in many streaming services and e-book files that do not allow copying or other manipulation.

The main purpose of *read-only* is to control how you use the data.

**Write-protected**

If data is *write-protected*, the data is protected from modification (no editing, appending,etc.) but may be able to be dealt with in other ways. It may be able to be copied, possibly concatenated (as long as the body remains intact), moved, and otherwise handled. Often copies of the data can be made and they may be able to be fully edited and modified.

The main purpose of *write-protected* is to ensure that there is a clean unchanged version of the data.

Devices and media are often characterized as *read-only* or *write-protected*, but this is really an indication of how they handle data. Often they are capable of various modes that can be changed by the user. Old floppy discs had either a notch or a switch that allowed them to turn on and off their *write-protected* feature.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that you cannot *copy* read-only data. In the physical world as much as in the digital world, read access is usually all you require in order to copy data.

Comment: @us2012 I don't disagree that almost any data that can be perceived can be copied, manipulated, hacked. But data is often delivered in a fashion that *tries* to make it *read-only*. I also agree that many people call data *read-only* when it is in fact only *write-protected*.

Comment: No downvotes, but I think your answer would be more accurate if you removed references to things like copying, erasing, and moving.  In the context of modern operating systems there are three operations for any file: read, write, execute.  A read-only file has write and execute permissions disabled.  If a user has only read permissions, she *can* by definition copy the file.  What she cannot do is append or edit the contents of the file, nor can she execute the file if it is executable in nature.  Conversely, a write protected file cannot be edited or modified, but it can be read or executed.

Comment: In practice, the term "write-protected" often refers not to file permissions, but rather to storage media (that is to say Tapes and/or Disks.)

Comment: @Lumberjack How would you characterize files like some e-book formats and streamed media files that are copy and move restricted? Is there another term that describes these limitations?

Comment: @bib We would refer to such protection as DRM or [Digital Rights Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management.)   Typically one would say that an eBook has "copy protection, copy prevention, and/or copy control."

Answer (score 0):

Write-protected puts the emphasis on the user having made a conscious decision to prevent writes.

If you have a device that for some technical reason can only be read, and not written (e.g. a non-recordable CD) then it would be correct to call that read-only, but wrong to call it write-protected.

In common use (I have worked for many years in IT security) read-only is used much more commonly than write-protected.

Answer (score 0):

*Read-only memory*, for instance, means that its data cannot be changed (cannot be overwritten) and there is absolutely no physical way to access and alter the content of that memory.

*Write-protected* sounds like you need some kind of a "security key" in order to break that protection and only then you would be able to change the content of the that device. An example is when you change permissions of a Unix directory to allow or prevent individual or group access to (and hence changing content in) that directory.

Answer (score 0):

They may sound the same colloquially but strictly speaking "read only" means one can only read the data, while "write protected" means one can't modify it. It isn't obvious that "read" and "write" are the only possible options, however. As an example, in Unix and Unix-based systems, there are three distinct kinds of permissions for a file: read, write, and execute (such as in running a program). "Read only" would mean that you have only have permission to read the file, while "write protected" would mean you can both read and execute the file. That is just one example, the precise meaning would depend upon the context.